# Ho to determine with following statements using logic :

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Been trying really hard to get to a conclusion using these statments

Consider the following two statements:
1.  The book is either at Anna’s house or at Mary’s house. Assume A means “the book is at Anna’s house” and M means “the book is at Mary’s house”. We can represent this as A V M.
2.  We also know that the book can’t be at both places at the same time, i.e.
(A & ¬M) V (¬A & M).
3.  If the book is not at Anna’s house, then it must be at Mary’s house, i.e.
¬A  M

Given these three statements, can we determine where the book is?

Explain you answer in detail step by step. You must prove your “yes/no” answer.

Answer (score 2):

No we cannot. Suppose it is at Marys house. Then both statements are true. Suppose it is at Annas house. Then both statements are true. Therefore we cannot use the statements to deduce where the book is. In a problem like this you should think about what the problem is actually saying, rather then then putting it in formal logic terms. I suspect the formal notation is clouding your understanding rather than enhancing it.

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't determine where the book is.  Notice that the third statement follows from the first statement. For if the book is at Anna's house or Mary's house, and the book is not at Anna's house, then it must be at Mary's house.